# maven `exec:exec` fails but `exec:java` succeeds

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I learned that the [Exec Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html) have two goals, `exec:exec`, and `exec:java`, but I don't know how to specify them:

In my case, the `mvn exec:java` works well, but the `mvn exec:exec` keeps throwing exceptions like below:

`[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (run) @ allnewmaker ---
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "exec" (in directory "/home/huang/Desktop/Project/Make/allnewmaker"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:620)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec (Java13CommandLauncher.java:61)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch (DefaultExecutor.java:279)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:804)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:751)`

my `pom.xml` is like this:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bar</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>foo</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!--default: java-->
                    <executable>exec</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-i</argument>
                        <argument>${argInput}</argument>
                        <argument>-o</argument>
                        <argument>${argOutput}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <mainClass>org.qoros.maker.AllNewMaker</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your pom you have the name of your executable:
exec
And the name "exec" is not a valid executable name.

You configure your goal there:

```
<execution>
    <id>bar</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

If you want to use exec:java, you need to change your goal from exec to java.

I am referring the usage page:
https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html

Let me know if something need clarification!

Comment: You should have it in your logs: 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (run) @ allnewmaker ---
where  exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:GOAL

Comment: It is visible when I use the "-X" option